# how to create Html-document from scratch using node module 'html-element'?

Tags: javascript

For example something like this:

```js
const HTML = require('html-element');
const doc = `<body>
</body>`;
const page = HTML.document.createElement(doc)
page.appendChild('<div>1</div>')
page.appendChild('<div>2</div>')
page.appendChild('<div>3</div>')
console.log(page)
```

but, of course, this is the wrong way, because

```
page.document.querySelectorAll("div")
```

isn't working. How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `childNodes` property on the `page` object to get all `divs`.

```js
// var document = require('html-element').document;

const HTML = require('html-element');
const doc = `<body></body>`;
const page = HTML.document.createElement(doc)
page.appendChild('<div>1</div>')
page.appendChild('<div>2</div>')
page.appendChild('<div>3</div>')

// childNodes ✅
const divs = page.childNodes;
for (const div of divs) {
  console.log(`div =`, div)
}
```

> screenshot

[image]

### refs

https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-element